# Error not being displayed for checkbox inside tab when using AngularJS and Bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using AngularJS and Bootstrap. I have the following problem:
I want to display an error on top of the tabs but for some reason it doesn't seem to be working. So the following never gets displayed:

```html
<p ng-show="forma.isTabSelected.$error.required">Please select Tab.</p>
```

The only way for that to be displayed is by taking the checkbox outside the tab-heading tag (I don't want to do that).

Here's the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/24Oo6jadox6NZEybDjaf?p=preview)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You could hack this by adding a second hidden input that is outside of the tab and shares a model with the input that is in the tab. e.g.: http://plnkr.co/edit/3iIy5ERCtYcvi7krGrSg?p=preview . But hopefully someone has a better solution.

Comment: That did work fine. I'll use that in the meantime. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In order to get access to the scope in the Tabset, you should prefix your variable with the model name:

```
ng-model="forma.isTabSelected"
```

The tab creates a child scope. You need to bind your input to a model in the parent scope.